# Any way to export, remove and later restore git tags?

Tags: git, tags

My project has now more than 50 tags,most of them are in remote and local , and I would like to save the unused ones, remove them, but keeping the possibility to restore one or more of them later.

I don't see any mean to do it, does anyone has a clue ?

Comment: I guess you could use `git tag --format="git tag %(refname:strip=2) %(objectname)"` to create a list of commands that can recreate those tags?

Comment: OMG that's pretty crafty !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a list of commands to re-add current tags using

```
git tag --format="git tag %(refname:strip=2) %(objectname)"
```

Also you could run `git pack-refs --all` and then backup `.git/packed-refs`
(It's a text-file that will contain all refs, e.g. tags; after running `git pack-refs --all`. Otherwise some tags may only be found in `.git/refs/tags/`)